# Is it possible to compile and test Groovy source files for Java 6 with Gradle 5?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, compilation

Based on customer requirements I am currently stuck on Java 6 and therefore I am using Gradle 2.14.1 now. In order to be able to upgrade Gradle to the latest version and still compile and test for Java 6, I followed the instructions within the official userguide – see [Groovy Cross Compilation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/groovy_plugin.html?_ga=2.104117824.1378050333.1556776816-1052217858.1501769777#sec:groovy_cross_compilation).

From my point of view, with the above configuration, compiling the following sample Groovy class should result in an error since it uses classes which were introduced in Java 8.

```java
import groovy.transform.TypeChecked

@TypeChecked
class SomeGroovyClass {
    Optional<String> someGroovyMethod() {
        return Optional.empty()
    }
}
```

But somehow the Gradle build is successful. Am I missing something here? How can I use the latest Gradle version and still compile and test Groovy source files and Java source files for Java 6?

If I convert the above class into a Java class, the build fails like expected.

I also created a small test project demonstrating my issue. The project can be found here – [Github](https://github.com/knusprigerschweinsbraten/gradle-java6-build-sample).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I have been living in a similar situation off and on for the past few years.

To figure this out, I created a sample mini-project with the following `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'

repositories { 
  jcenter()
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies { 
    compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.4.15"
}



if (JavaVersion.current() != JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6) {
  // findJava6Jvm is defined in java-versions.gradle
  // and returns a gradle JavaInfo instance.
  def java6Jvm = findJava6Jvm()

  if (!rootProject.ext.has('hasPrintedJavaVersionNote')) {
    println "**************** java version notice ****************"
    println "NOTE: the gradle process and the source compilation"
    println "      are using different versions of java:"
    println ""
    println "    gradle process uses:       ${JavaVersion.current()}"
    println "    source complilation uses:  1.6"
    println ""
    println "*****************************************************"
    rootProject.ext.hasPrintedJavaVersionNote = true
  }

  sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
  targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6

  tasks.withType(AbstractCompile) {
    options.with {
      fork = true
      forkOptions.executable = java6Jvm.javacExecutable
    }
  }

  tasks.withType(GroovyCompile) {
    groovyOptions.with {
      fork = true
    }
  }

  tasks.withType(Javadoc) {
    executable = java6Jvm.javadocExecutable
  }

  tasks.withType(Test) {
    executable = java6Jvm.javaExecutable
  }

  tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
    executable = java6Jvm.javaExecutable
  }
}


def findJava6Jvm(Closure extraUsage = null) {
  if (JavaVersion.current().isJava6()) {
    // if we are already using java 6 to launch gradle, just return 
    // the javac for the current jvm
    return org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.current()
  }

  def failOnCondition = { condition, msg -> 
    if (condition) {
      println """
      Executing the gradle build with a JDK different from java 1.6
      (i.e. java 7, 8, etc) requires that you provide the build 
      with enough information so that it can still locate a java 1.6
      jdk for source code compilation. 

      If the build can not locate a java 6 jdk, you can help it out by 
      specifying one of the following properties: 

        JAVA_HOME_6 environment variable (example: \"export JAVA_HOME_6=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6/\")
        JAVA_HOME_6 system property (-DJAVA_HOME_6=<path>)
        JAVA_HOME_6 gradle project property (-PJAVA_HOME_6=<path>)
      """.stripIndent()  

      if (extraUsage != null) {
        extraUsage()
      }
      println msg.stripIndent()        
      throw new GradleException("No 1.6.x jdk found!") 
    }
  }

  def name = 'JAVA_HOME_6'
  def custom = [System.env[name], System.properties[name], properties[name]].find { it }
  failOnCondition !custom, """
      ERROR: Please set the JAVA_HOME_6 property in one of the above specified
             ways"""

  def jdkDir = file(custom)
  failOnCondition !jdkDir.isDirectory(), """
      ERROR: The configured JAVA_HOME_6 setting:
      
        $custom
      
      does not point to a directory on the local file system.
      Please set this variable to the JAVA_HOME of a 1.6.x
      jdk"""


  def fs = File.separator
  def jdkJavac = file("$jdkDir${fs}bin${fs}javac").canonicalFile
  if( !jdkJavac.isFile() ) jdkJavac = file( jdkJavac.path + ".exe" )

  failOnCondition !jdkJavac.isFile(), """
      ERROR: Could not locate a bin/javac executable file under 
             the configured JAVA_HOME_6 setting: 
    
        $custom \n"""

  def process = [jdkJavac, "-version"].execute()
  process.waitForOrKill(5000)
  def version = process.err.text.readLines().first()
  failOnCondition !version?.contains('1.6.'), """
      ERROR: The configured JAVA_HOME_6 setting:
    
        $custom
    
      points at a non 1.6 jdk, 'java -version' reports $version!"""

  // after all the validations pass, reutrn the jdk javac path
  org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.forHome(jdkDir)
}
```

and I dropped the class in your question into a file at:

```
java-version-experiment ~> tree src/
src/
└── main
    └── groovy
        └── com
            └── somepackage
                └── SomeGroovyClass.groovy
```

Given the above, when I run a gradle compile of my source using java 8:

```
java-version-experiment ~>  export JAVA_HOME_6=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6_121-oracle

java-version-experiment ~>  setjava java-8-oracle 
PATH updated - JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

java-version-experiment ~> gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.10.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2018-09-19 18:10:15 UTC
Revision:     b4d8d5d170bb4ba516e88d7fe5647e2323d791dd

Kotlin DSL:   1.0-rc-6
Kotlin:       1.2.61
Groovy:       2.4.15
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.11 compiled on March 23 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_201 (Oracle Corporation 25.201-b09)
OS:           Linux 4.18.0-17-generic amd64


java-version-experiment ~>  gradle build

> Configure project :
**************** java version notice ****************
NOTE: the gradle process and the source compilation
      are using different versions of java:

    gradle process uses:       1.8
    source complilation uses:  1.6

*****************************************************

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed

java-version-experiment ~>
```

it seems that the class does get compiled using java 6. On linux you can check this using a command line hex editor on the class files:

```
~> od -j 7 -N 1 -t d1 build/classes/groovy/main/com/somepackage/SomeGroovyClass.class 
0000007   50
0000010
~>
```

which essentially pulls out byte 7 (zero based) from the class file where `50` is what we are interested in. The relevant java version numbers are:

```
Java 6 uses major version 50
Java 7 uses major version 51
Java 8 uses major version 52
Java 9 uses major version 53
Java 10 uses major version 54
Java 11 uses major version 55
```

in other words, it seems to me that using the `forkOptions.executable` on the compile task works and the classes are indeed compiled using java 6.

However, it also seems to me that the classpaths leak. What I mean by this is that it seems that even though you compile using the java 6 executable, the java 8 classpath and APIs leak into the compilation process.

Like you stated, the above compilation should have failed, but didn't. I am still at at loss as to why this happens and more importantly how to prevent the classpath leakage.

Any gradle gurus please feel free to chime in here, I would be very interested in getting to the bottom of this issue.

<< edit >>

Found the following:

> Compiling and testing for Java 6 or Java 7
>
> The Groovy compiler will always be executed with the same version of Java that was used to start Gradle. You should set sourceCompatibility and targetCompatibility to 1.6 or 1.7. If you also have Java source files, you can follow the same steps as for the Java plugin to ensure the correct Java compiler is used.

in the gradle docs at:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/groovy_plugin.html

So it seems this is not possible for groovy. The 7th byte in the classfile seems to be controlled by the:

```
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
```

setting, i.e. even when using pure java 8 and setting targetCompatibility, we get `50` in the class major version byte.

<< edit 2 >>

verified that this works for java files. Added a java file under `src/main/java/com/somepackage/SomeJavaClass.java` with the exact same build file as above configuring a dual vm compilation scenario.

Result:

```
gradle clean build

> Configure project :
**************** java version notice ****************
NOTE: the gradle process and the source compilation
      are using different versions of java:

    gradle process uses:       1.8
    source complilation uses:  1.6

*****************************************************

> Task :compileJava FAILED
/home/mbjarland/projects/java-version-experiment/src/main/java/com/somepackage/SomeJavaClass.java:5: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Optional
location: class com.somepackage.SomeJavaClass
    public Optional<String> someJavaMethod() {
           ^
/home/mbjarland/projects/java-version-experiment/src/main/java/com/somepackage/SomeJavaClass.java:6: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable Optional
location: class com.somepackage.SomeJavaClass
        return Optional.empty();
               ^
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed with exit code 1; see the compiler error output for details.

BUILD FAILED in 1s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
```

which is what you would expect.

Conclusion after long winded exploration: this works for java files as expected, not possible for groovy files.

Comment: Your findings are spot on. Groovy compilation is performed by the JVM version that is running Gradle, and this cannot be changed